# What is the meaning of dot and square bracket in VB.NET

Tags: .net, vb.net

I came across this statement :

```
   Dim userStartup As UserStartup = userStartup.[Default]
```

Now after going through few posts, I under stood square brackets for types, but why the dot.

Comment: Its how you escape keywords to use them as variable or property names.  The dot is referencing a prop or var named "Default"  on `userStartup`

Comment: Here's some [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172802.aspx) about the member access operator. ["An escaped identifier is an identifier delimited by square brackets"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa711644(v=vs.71).aspx)